# java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: java, rmi

this is a simple RMI program,howerver,it always throw exception when I run HelloClient.java .

create remote interface

```
public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

create remote class

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
public class HelloImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello {

    protected HelloImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("HelloImpl:" + name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

create server:

```
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class HelloServer {
    public static final int port = 1099;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            }
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            HelloImpl impl = new HelloImpl();
            registry.rebind("//SEJ1T1DYN68BZBF:1099/HelloService", impl);
            String[] names = registry.list();
            for (String name : names) {
                System.out.println(name);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

create client:

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class HelloClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            Hello hello = (Hello) registry
                    .lookup("//SEJ1T1DYN68BZBF:1099/HelloService");
            System.out.println(hello.sayHello("javamaj blog"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the exception is:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:10)
```

The environment :
jdk  1.7 +eclipse+window xp

Answer (score 1):

There is something other than an RMI Registry running at port 1099 in the client host.

However unless the client host and the server host are the same host, you're looking up the wrong Registry anyway. You need to call `getRegistry()` with the server hostname, so you're looking up the Registry at the server host: the one that the server bound to.

Comment: @user2963824 Did this fix your problem?